# Wix website-Download the entered data in excel format

Tags: javascript, html, excel, database

Currently the client is using a Wix free website builder.And they want to  have  all the data in this form including the drag and drop objects into the baskets that the user has performed. I m going to embed this code into the Wix page.

```
<div>Drag and drop Food Items into baskets.</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="name">Your name:</label>
<br />
<input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" />
<br />
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="email">Your email:</label>
<br />
<input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" />
<br />
</div>
<div id="container">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="image1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://i01.i.aliimg.com/photo/v9/117248521_1/Guava_fruits_seeds_Psidium_guajava_.jpg_50x50.jpg');"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="image2" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://www.farmfreshtoyou.com/media/wysiwyg/fresh_fruits/45.jpg');"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="image3" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://www.chicmags.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/10-Fruits-for-Hair-Growth-50x50.png');"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="image4" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://img.ehowcdn.com/other-people/ehow/images/a07/dg/ce/list-acid-soil-tolerant-vegetables-800x800.jpg');"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="image5" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://a.ftscrt.com/static/images/food_groups/vegetables.jpg');"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="image6" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://www.howmanycaloriescounter.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Eating-Colourful-Fruits-And-Vegetables-50x50.jpg');"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="image7" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_uQMacmrsRNA/TK5gis6gXWI/AAAAAAAAAxM/BuzxU9IPA24/s1600/dessert.png');"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="image8" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v1/503145125_2/dessert-decorators-Food-decoration-pen-fondant-decoration-pen-chocolate-cake-pen-free-shiping.jpg_50x50.jpg');"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="image9" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/50x50/1129209.jpg');"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="boxB" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)">Eaten more than once Basket</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="boxF" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)">Eaten more than twice Basket</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="boxF" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)">Eaten more than thrice Basket</div>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way that I can download the entered data into the excel format in a wix website?
If it is not possible I want to send  the data into the 3rd party  database and then Download it in Excel format.
Is this over ambitious?

Or is there any third party app that I an embed in the Wix web page

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bloodviper9000/wuea5spL/2/)

Comment: jotform.com

   -if i understand your question correctly this should help

Comment: @racecarjonathan It is fine,but can I implement the drag and drop multiple answers into one question?

Comment: The closest thing I can find to what I want is shown here

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-quiz/drag-drop-quiz-d2.html